# Is some one using RDP on 3389 to access our server?

Tags: active-directory, vpn, firewall, rdp

As far as I know we do not have a VPN. However, another sys admin at the corp I work at is "remoting in" from outside the network...As far as I know the only way to do this is forward traffic from our router.  There is no such rule that I see.

My concern is that our AD admin account is open to the internet.

I checked the router for the forwarded ports and looked for a VPN on one of our VM's.  I see nothing but cannot understand how he is able to do this.

I would assume you either use a VPN or forward the appropriate ports.  Are there other methods I am unaware of ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. You could ask at [Super User](https://superuser.com/), which is for general computing questions.

Comment: But a simple answer to your question: The right way is VPN. You could also forward ports for either RDP or VNC. Or use a program that initiates the connection from inside and keeps the connection open to a server, like [LogMeIn](https://www.logmein.com/). VPN is the most secure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will take it over to that sub.  It stated "not for IT, only for home networking" in the description for SuperUser, so i didn't place it there.

Comment: Or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: check if he's using TeamViewer or another program that works the same way